# Как убрать дефолтную анимацию нажатия на button в IE 9, 10, 11?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, internet-explorer

В IE 9, 10, 11 прыгают `button` при нажатии. Свойства `margin: 0` и `padding: 0` на псевдоклассы `:active` и `:focus` проблемы не решают. Пример съезжания кнопок на видео:
https://monosnap.com/file/Lcln7cTFX0lPwWjbeu5JnQA5ikcefn

Comment: может код таки покажете с минимальным воспроизводимым примером

Comment: Я на видео мало что понял, но от балды предложу `line-height` выставить какой-нибудь

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму обычный button без стилей откройте в IE и увидите. Какой пример вы хотите? Или вы под каждым вопросом одно и тоже вставляете?

Comment: @AndreyYanov открыл. Никаких проблем не увидел. Ловите минус, пока не будет минимального воспроизводимого примера (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму потому что кто-то путает Edge и IE.

Comment: @AndreyYanov, ага, я edge от ie после стольких лет веб разработки отличить не могу (11.0.9600.18059 кстати).

Comment: Я тут пытаюсь вам сказать что я нихрена не понимаю в чем вопрос, вам не нравится дефолтный эффект нажатия на кнопку конкретно в IE или что?

Comment: Да! Разве я непонятно описал и разве видео не показывают проблему?

Comment: @AndreyYanov описали непонятно, я с первого прочтения не понял, и со следующего тоже. С просмотра видео тоже не понял. Понял только посмотрев ответ soledar10. По правилам сайта существенные нюансы вопроса должны содержаться в вопросе. Минус я пожалуй уберу, но пожалуйста попробуйте сформулировать вопрос получше

Comment: Ну а код-то где?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Глобальное решение без лишних вложенных элементов:**

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
}

button:active, button:focus {
    position: гelative;
    background: #999;
}

/* стили только для IE9 */ 
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) { 
  button:active, button:focus {
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
  }
}

/* стили только для IE10 и IE11 */ 
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 
  button:active, button:focus {
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
    click me
</button>
```

Comment: В ие11 не работает.

Comment: также проверил не работает в  ie10, ie11

Answer (score 10):

```css
button > span,
button:active span, 
button:focus span {
    position: relative; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Button</span></button>
```

Comment: А причем тут span?

Comment: span тут не причем, можете использовать любой другой тег внутри button. это хак чтобы убрать люфт у button в ie

Comment: Контент располагается непосредственно в button, а не span. Также в button может вообще быть только i.

Comment: Если в button напишу i и span, сработает хак? Такой селектор сработает? button > * {
    position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
}

Comment: сейчас на маке, не могу проверить, поэтому спрашиваю.

Comment: должно работать

Comment: Я кстати не понимаю зачем тогда нам <button> если попирать всю семантику разметки хаками, если это произвольно стилизованные управляющие элементы, делаем их дивами и меньше думаем на резетящими костылями

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму button семантичен, вот только дизайнерам не нравится прыганье кнопки. Да и пользователям тоже. Сайт должен во всех браузерах работать. Ну а использовать вместо кнопки span - бред же, согласитесь.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму тут разработчикам IE нужно вопрос задать, зачем они такую чушь делали, если разметку приходиться попирать хаками, чтобы добиться нормального отображения.

Comment: @AndreyYanov, нет не бред. Абсолютно большая часть spa обходится где-то пятью тегами из которых большая часть дивы и спаны. Вот если вам надо чтобы хорошо поисковиками размечалось то да, от семантики html не убежать.

Comment: @AndreyYanov, button семантичен, а вот спан внутри батона - уже нет. Поэтому я и говорю, если у вас синглпейдж (а у вас - он) - зачем полумеры?

Comment: @AndreyYanov, то есть смотрите, в приложении есть 4 семантических слоя. Основной, как приложение устроено "простыми словами", и три побочных, которые стараются отражать основной. Разметка отображающаяся в html (семантические теги), цсс-классы (бэм и иже с ним), и компонентная модель на js. Вот хаком Вы уже семантический слой разметки нарушаете. Но если он вам не нужен особо, то и пофигу. Во многих синглпейджах он не нужен и его игнорируют чтобы не умножать сущности.

Comment: @soledar10 не работает =(

Comment: @Vadizar в ie10, ie11 работает

Comment: @soledar10 а с добавлением кастомных свойств? Попробуйте border и paddinп добавить.

Comment: @Vadizar работает https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5euzc5xj/

Comment: @soledar10 сработало, спасибо. Минус убрал, плюс поставил

Comment: @AndreyYanov а вы протестировали перед тем, как принимать ответ? в моём ие11 это решение работает, а вот принятый правильным ответ — нет.

Answer (score 5):

Самое простое и надежное: заменить <button> на <a>
В бутстрапе, который писался не одним человеком, поведение button не погашено. в своем проекте использую <a>
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons - в примере кнопка Link

Также можно подключить для ИЕ css, который компенсирует смещение без добавления внутренних тегов: 
.btn
{
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
}
.btn:active {
    padding: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
}

возможно появится дополнительное нежелательное поведение соседних объектов, но в эту сторону можно покопать.

Comment: Потому что Бутстрап, как и normalize.css - чушь. Там outline у полей тоже не погашено, однако ничего сложного в этом нет. Так что делай себе кумиров и думать, что если они не могут это сделать, то и я - глупо. Нужно думать своей головой. Использовать <a> в данном примере - невалидны. Ссылка != кнопка.

Answer (score 3):

Решение тестировалось на IE 11. Работает фокус с вычитанием по одному пикселю слева и сверху у внутренних полей и прибавлением справа и снизу, соответственно:

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid;
}


button:active {
  padding: 9px 11px 11px 9px;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: Зато в остальных браузерах прыгает =) Поганое решение. Или предлагаете использовать хаки для определения IE? В любом случае, для каждой кнопки прописывать стили для исправление в IE - бред.

Comment: @Vadizar а шо делать? Главное, удовлетворяет условиям поставленной задачи.

Comment: не очень удобный вариант, хоть и работает